Looking for cartoon with a comatose superhero-type leader and a zombie
I'm looking for this cartoon I used to love when I was a child.
I remember there was this male superhero-type character (he was the leader) who was comatose or in suspended animation. The guy eventually wakes up / is cured from whatever he had. He had been in that state for some time.
In this team he was a part of, there were a zombie or a skeleton (it was explicitly said this team member was undead), a little girl, and her sister. The little girl ends up dying, but if I recall correctly, she leaves like a hologram or AI of herself.
Shortly after her death, the little girl's sister finds one of such holograms. The older sister asked her if she's alive, but the hologram says something like: "If you're seeing this, it means I'm dead."
It looked American, possibly late 80's to early 90's.
Update: The little girl who died had a "X" somewhere in her name.

Do you know what was the cartoon style? Or how it looked?

@GustavoGabriel I don't remember; only that it was good-quality animation.
